# Wordpress Admin bar keeps appearing to visitors

Tags: wordpress, caching, nginx, redis

Can't really get to the bottom of this issue. I'm running a Wordpress news website on a Debian WHM / Cpanel server. The server runs nginx and I am using redis for the website's cache. I am also using the nginx helper plugin for Wordpress.

The problem is that the Wordpress Admin bar keeps appearing to visitors, even visitors who never logged in on the website. They can't really go inside the site's admin panel as if they click on a link in the Wordpress Admin bar they are being asked for a username and password but this is still disturbing.

Any one of you experienced this before and know of a way to fix it ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow! Stack Overflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), however, your question appears to be more about managing Wordpress. Please see [ask] for more information as to why this question is not on topic for Stack Overflow. You might be able to find help on a Wordpress technical support site.

Comment: Did you enable Purge option and choose Redis cache as Caching method in Nginx helper option page? And try your luck with [Redis Object Cache](https://vi.wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/) plugin. Remember hit Enable Object Cache after activate it.

Answer (score 0):

for display admin bar to all users you have to install this plugin 
[Try this link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/always-show-admin-bar/)

and also try this code

```
function my_function_admin_bar($content) {
    return false;     
 }
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

i have not check this code yet but i used [This-Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/show_admin_bar) for reference purpose.

Comment: I've used this, added code to the functions.php file of the theme however no luck. it still pops up. After i flush the redis cache the bar doesn't appear, but 30 minutes later.. it shows up

Comment: it help you or not?? @Stephan

Answer (score 0):

You are caching html version of the site. I have been facing this issue for so long. This can be so frustrating, I know.

Problem: When site cache is cleared and you are logged in as admin so the caching system will cache the page from a logged in user/admin. Which means they will cache the admin bar as well.

Solution: There are some ways you can try but the best possible way it to add this code `function.php` to hide admin bar and only show it on pages where needed with adding a string `show=true` to URL E.g. `https://www.example.com/?show`

```
function ba_hide_admin_bar() {
  if ($_GET['showAB'] || $_GET['show'] || $_GET['ab'] || $_GET['AB']) {
    show_admin_bar(true);
    return;
  } 
  show_admin_bar(false);
}
add_action( 'init', 'ba_hide_admin_bar' );
```

Or For short [Install this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-show-admin-bar/)